# Extra text in mail body when using phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

I am using phpmailer for a simple email form (no html or attachments) on my website.
The mails have the following after the mail body:

```
cpsession - closed

cprelogin - no

__utmt - 1

__utma - 128921630.1494146512.1453467768.1453480322.1453518059.4

__utmb - 128921630.1.10.1453518059

__utmc - 128921630

__utmz - 128921630.1453467768.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
```

Please let me know how to prevent this from appearing at the end of email body.
Thanks a lot in advance..

Here is the sending part:

```
<?php
require("lib/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$email_subject = "Message from Website";

foreach ($_REQUEST as $field_name => $value){
if (!empty($value)) $body .= "$field_name - $value\n\r";
}
$email_from = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name_from = $_REQUEST['name'];

$email_to = "receivermail@yahoo.com"; 
$email_cc = "receivermail@gmail.com"; 

$mail->AddAddress($email_to);
$mail->AddCC($email_cc);
$mail->AddReplyTo($email_from , $name_from);

$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Subject = $email_subject;

if(!$mail->Send())
{   echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">";
    echo 'alert("Unable to send email. Please try again!")';
    echo"</script>";
}
else {echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">";
      echo 'alert("Your mail been sent successfully!")';
      echo"</script>";}

echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">";
echo "window.location = 'contact.html'";
echo "</script>";  
?>
```

and Here is the form:

```
<form id="contact" action="conmailer.php"  method="post" name="contact">                       
                         <fieldset id="personal">
                            <input class="validate[required] text-input medinp" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" tabindex="1" />
                            <br />                  
                            <input class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input medinp " name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" tabindex="2" />
                            <input name="address" class="addr" type="text" />
                            <br />
                            <input class="medinp" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Your Phone No." tabindex="3" />
                            <br />  
                            <input class="biginp" name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject" tabindex="4" />
                            <br />
                            <textarea class="validate[required] text-input" name="msg" placeholder="Message" tabindex="5"></textarea>
                            <br />
                            <input class="button1" type="submit" value=" SEND" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Comment: provide some code related to the sending part to look for what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of PHPMailer, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

You don't show what your'e putting in `$body` - PHPMailer just sends whatever you put in there. In your case it looks like you're dumping the contents of the `$_COOKIE` superglobal into your body contents. So check what you're putting in there, and your problem will go away.

Comment: Sorry, I am a PHP beginner.. Please let me know how to prevent the $_COOKIE contents from getting to the message body. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Er, nothing, it doesn't get in there if you don't put it in there! You need to find where `$body` is set.

Comment: Is it here:
foreach ($_REQUEST as $field_name => $value){
if (!empty($value)) $body .= "$field_name - $value\n\r";
}

Comment: Yes; $_REQUEST includes $_COOKIE

Comment: Your form is using the post method, so use $_POST.